# Why there are two maximum value of $p$ exist in a plot of logarithm likelihood?

Tags: parameter-estimation

The plot of the logarithm of the likelihood shown below indicates that there are two values of $p$ that give the same maximum value for the likelihood.

May I know why this happens and find an equation satisfied by these values.

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: It happens because of the specifics of the (unknown to us) problem. And if you are able to plot, don't you already have an equation?

Comment: Actually it is a question(including the plot) in a paper without any given information such as which random variable with which distribution is involved...